# i'm trying to get expression from each sentences

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get certain sentences with different type of sentences from a number of references

this is the references

```
Goldberg, Yoav (2016). "A Primer on Neural Network Models for Natural Language Processing". Journal of Artificial Intelligence Research. 57: 345–420. arXiv:1807.10854.

Goodfellow, Ian; Bengio, Yoshua; Courville, Aaron (2016). Deep Learning. MIT Press.

Choe, Do Kook; Charniak, Eugene. "Parsing as Language Modeling". EMNLP 2016.

Vinyals, Oriol; et al. "Grammar as a Foreign Language" (PDF). NIPS2015.

Winograd, Terry (1971). Procedures as a Representation for Data in a Computer Program for Understanding Natural Language (Thesis).

Schank, Roger C.; Abelson, Robert P. (1977). Scripts, Plans, Goals, and Understanding: An Inquiry Into Human Knowledge Structures. Hillsdale: Erlbaum. ISBN 0-470-99033-3.

Mark Johnson. How the statistical revolution changes (computational) linguistics. Proceedings of the EACL 2009 Workshop on the Interaction between Linguistics and Computational Linguistics.

Philip Resnik. Four revolutions. Language Log, February 5, 2011.

Kishorjit, N.; Vidya, Raj RK.; Nirmal, Y.; Sivaji, B. (2012). "Manipuri Morpheme Identification" (PDF). Proceedings of the 3rd Workshop on South and Southeast Asian Natural Language Processing (SANLP). COLING 2012, Mumbai, December 2012: 95–108.

Mittal (2011). "Versatile question answering systems: seeing in synthesis". IJIIDS. 5 (2): 119–142. doi:10.1504/IJIIDS.2011.038968.

PASCAL Recognizing Textual Entailment Challenge (RTE-7) https://tac.nist.gov//2011/RTE/

Yi, Chucai; Tian, Yingli (2012), "Assistive Text Reading from Complex Background for Blind Persons", Camera-Based Document Analysis and Recognition, Springer Berlin Heidelberg, pp. 15–28, CiteSeerX 10.1.1.668.869, doi:10.1007/978-3-642-29364-1_2, ISBN 9783642293634
```

as you can see each sentences is different, and everytime i'm trying to get a certain sentence from the references, not all the sentences is get correctly

this is one of the expression i tried 
`([.]((?<=.)(.*)\.?))`
and this is the result
[image]

the result is different and not all of them are get correctly.
and since i'm new into the regex thing, i still don't really know what expression to use, please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like all the sentences you want to match are immediately after:

- a period followed by a space, (match with `(?<=\. )`), or
- a `,` which is *not* right after a word character, followed by a space (match with `(?<=\B, )`)

And, all matches start with a capital letter, possibly preceeded by a `"` (match with `"?[A-Z]`)

Put all those conditions together, and you get:

```
(?:(?<=\. )|(?<=\B, ))"?[A-Z].+
```

https://regex101.com/r/gATQDH/1

Comment: thanks, the starting sentences now are correct, but the problem is the sentences does not stop at the correct period

Comment: Your question didn't specify that you wanted the match to end at a certain point. Maybe you want to change to something like add [`(?: \(\w+\))?\..*`](https://regex101.com/r/gATQDH/2) to the end of the pattern - only match up until another `.`. The last reference is problematic because it's using `,` delimiters, not `.` delimiters. I don't think a general regex solution is possible for that format without the `"`s

Comment: thank you, although i'm still confused with the expression at least i can learn from it.

Comment: another question, i have this expression ```^([^.]+)``` it should get every 1st sentences from each reference. but it get 1st reference only. how do i do it?

Comment: Make sure to use use the multiline flag, else `^` will only match the start of the string